# Maven Release Process - Best Practices

Tags: maven, svn, maven-release-plugin

Please help me understand on the below

1. What is the release process that is practiced in general(standard practice)?
2. Can we do a release from branch?
3. How can we merge the code from branch to trunk, if we have to do a release only from branch(is there any plugin for this)?

Vijay

Answer (score 0):

1. Standard release practice : 
   Every Software delivery is based on a SDLC model ( waterfall , V or Agile...) which have different phases and the common onces are :
   1.Requirement Analysis
   2.Design (High level design document and Low level design document)
   3.Code
   4.Test
   5.Deploy
   6.Release to end customer

To manage a release various practices are followed to ensure that the end-product should be exactly similar to the requirements.

During a release :
1. Release notes
2. Release Matrix has been maintained to keep track of what is going in which release and which release version has been deployed to which environment .

Once the design , code , testing gets completed on getting a final go-ahead the product is tagged and released to end customer .

If any changes comes work will start on Minor release , for critical issues hotfix is used to be dispatched .

Best Practices as per my understanding :
1. Decide a proper model for the particular release according to end customer requirement.
2. Namimg convention shld be properly decided .
3. Release notes should be provided with each release and must be reviewed .

1. A Software product can be released from branch once it is tested and tagged .
   In Subversion there is concept of release branch as well. "http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html"
2. Merging branch back to trunk is called as branching back to trunk

You can follow the below mentioned steps:

1. Update the branch working copy and merge all the changes from trunk first into the branch.
2. Now the branch is in sync with trunk .
3. Checkout working copy of trunk and merge branch to trunk .

Make sure there must be no locally modified file before you perform merge :

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html

Regards

Jyotsna